# Avoid import tax when using spark implicits

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In my testing, I have a test trait to provide spark context:

```
trait SparkTestTrait {
    lazy val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
}
```

The problem is that I need to add an import in every test function:

```
test("test1) {
  import spark.implicits._
}
```

I managed to reduce this to on per file by adding to the SparkTestTrait the following:

```
object testImplicits extends SQLImplicits {
  protected override def _sqlContext: SQLContext = spark.sqlContext
}
```

and then in the constructor of the implementing file:

```
import testImplicits._
```

However, I would prefer to have these implicits imported to all classes implementing SparkTestTrait (I can't have SparkTestTrait extend SQLImplicits because the implementing classes already extend an abstract class).

Is there a way to do this?